# C# Запуск процесса в фоновом режиме

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь запустить консольное приложение через `Process.Start`. Мне совершенно не нужно, чтобы показывалось окно приложения, есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы процесс работал фоном?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1)** Если вы хотите запустить консольное приложения без окна консоли:

```
        var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "...",  // Путь к приложению
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**2)** Если вы сами разрабатываете консольное приложение, то выставите тип ***"Windows Application"*** в свойствах проекта. Это сделает его *"скрытым"* по умолчанию.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace hide
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```